# field not showing up in on section of report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

My questions are gradually getting more and more difficult so clearly you are teaching me well!
In this one I have a report that prints details on card confirmorisations.
All fields fill fine except when I changed the confirm request to a "turnaround Request" the field that does not show up in this case in CTYlong which just remains blank for all instances for "turnaround Requests". This is for ssrs 
I'll leave it to you!

```
IF @MsgType = 200 
BEGIN 
SELECT DISTINCT MsgType = 'confirm Request' , resp.dtTimeRPO as     HostTime , 
                                                          resp.sSTANExternalI as STAN , 
 resp.sterminal_TerminalID as TerminalID ,      resp.ssell_CardAcceptorIDCode as    

 sellID , resp.ssell_CardAcceptorNameLoc as   sellName ,   

 STUFF(resp.span_Pan,7,(LEN(resp.span_Pan)-10), REPLICATE('X',(LEN(resp.span_Pan)-10)))   
 as PAN , CAST(MONTH(resp.dtpan_ExpiryDate) as varchar(2)) + '/' +   
 CAST(YEAR(resp.dtpan_ExpiryDate) as char(4)) as ExpDate , CAST(resp.namounts_cAmount   
 as float)/100 as Amount , resp.namounts_CurrencyCodetx as CurrencyCode , 
 resp.nActionCode as RC , rc.rcInfo as RCDesc , resp.sconfirmCode as confirmCode , 
   ssell_CountryShort2 AS sell_Country , ctylong , 

    (SELECT DATEPART(ss, resp.dtTimeRPO - req.dtTimeRQI) FROM dbo.txHistory as    
   req (NOLOCK) 

 WHERE req.sSTANExternalI = resp.sSTANExternalI 
 AND 
 req.namounts_cAmount = resp.namounts_cAmount 
 AND req.dtLocalDateTime = resp.dtLocalDateTime 
 AND RTRIM(req.sPHProfile) = @Head 
AND (req.sconfirmCode = '' 
 AND req.nActionCode = 0) 
AND req.dtTimeRQI BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, -1, @StartDate) 
 AND @EndDate ) as Duration 
 FROM dbo.txHistory as resp (NOLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN dbo.replyCode as rc (NOLOCK) 
 ON resp.nActionCode = rc.rcCode 
 inner join country (nolock) 
 on nsell_countrycode = ctycode 
WHERE resp.dtTimeRPO 
BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND
 resp.eMTI = @MsgType
AND 
RTRIM(resp.sPHProfile) = @Head
AND NOT (resp.sconfirmCode = '' AND resp.nActionCode = 0) 
ORDER BY resp.dtTimeRPO 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
 SELECT DISTINCT MsgType = 'turnaround Request' , resp.dtTimeRPO as HostTime ,   
 resp.sSTANExternalI as STAN , resp.sterminal_TerminalID as TerminalID ,   
  resp.ssell_CardAcceptorIDCode as sellID , resp.ssell_CardAcceptorNameLoc   
  as sellName , STUFF(resp.span_Pan,7,(LEN(resp.span_Pan)-10), REPLICATE('X',
  (LEN(resp.span_Pan)-10))) as PAN , CAST(MONTH(resp.dtpan_ExpiryDate) as varchar(2)) +   
 '/' + CAST(YEAR(resp.dtpan_ExpiryDate) as char(4)) as ExpDate ,   
 CAST(resp.namounts_cAmount as float)/100 as Amount ,   
  resp.namounts_CurrencyCodetx as CurrencyCode , resp.nActionCode as RC , 
  rc.rcInfo as RCDesc , resp.sconfirmCode as confirmCode , 

  (SELECT DATEPART(ss, resp.dtTimeRPO - req.dtTimeRQI) 
 FROM dbo.txHistory as req (NOLOCK)
 WHERE req.sSTANExternalI = resp.sSTANExternalI AND req.namounts_cAmount =     
  resp.namounts_cAmount AND req.dtLocalDateTime = resp.dtLocalDateTime
 AND
  RTRIM(req.sPHProfile) = @Head
  AND 
  (req.eMTI = 420 AND req.nActionCode = 400)
 AND 
 req.dtTimeRQI BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, -1, @StartDate) AND @EndDate ) 
as Duration 
FROM dbo.txHistory as resp (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN dbo.replyCode as rc (NOLOCK) ON resp.nActionCode = rc.rcCode WHERE    
 resp.dtTimeRPO 
BETWEEN 
@StartDate 
 AND @EndDate AND resp.eMTI = @MsgType 
 AND RTRIM(resp.sPHProfile) = @Head 
 ORDER BY resp.dtTimeRPO END
```

Answer (score 3):

For Reversal Requests you are not including the `ctylong` field. Basically your columns don't line up in your two queries. You really should format your queries better as well, that was a nightmare to read.

edit: This is how I like to format my queries

```
SELECT
   column1,
   column2,
   column3
FROM
   table_1 INNER JOIN
   table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         column_4
      FROM
         table_3
   ) t3 ON table_2.id = t3.id
WHERE
   table_1.id = 1000 AND
   table_2.id = 2000
```